# Specifying min macos development target when building FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am struggling to set the development target for FFmpeg on MacOS. I am trying to aim for macOS 10.13. Usually this would be done through the `-mmacosx-version-min` flag. I have tried adding this to the `--extra-cflags` command line option however it seems to have no effect. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What errors do you get when you try compiling? Knowing HOW this is failing will help us better understand how to help you.

Comment: I don't get an error when compiling. The way it is failing is by the compiled library not having the specified macos development target. As I said my command line option has no effect.